# Widget script fails to load asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Okay. So this has been asked few times on stackoverflow but none of them solves my issue. I have to load tripadvisor widget in my angularjs website. So I tried it and it works great when I refresh the page. But the problem is if I navigate to another page and come back the widget disappears.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454416/including-tripadvisor-widget-in-angularjs-app). It works only for the widget with just the rating percentage. If I use that for the widget with latest reviews, it doesn't work.

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

I get the above error in the console. Any ideas?