# Tripadvisor Widget not working in Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, widget, tripadvisor

I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm trying to get a Tripadvisor widget working on my page. The widget works great in plain html but as soon as I include it in my component in angular it shows the image for the widget but the javasript does not execute so you don't see the content.

widget code I'm using:

```
<div id="TA_cdsscrollingravenarrow993" class="TA_cdsscrollingravenarrow"><ul id="QAlUXL" class="TA_links ZECPTIZB"><li id="esd1SQAAb" class="VkzA66nOe"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/t4b/Stacked_TA_logo.png" alt="TripAdvisor" class="widEXCIMG" id="CDSWIDEXCLOGO"/></a></li></ul></div><script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsscrollingravenarrow?amp;locationId=1529483&amp;border=true&amp;uniq=993&amp;lang=en_US&amp;display_version=2"></script>
```

I did try the example from [Including tripadvisor widget in angularjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454416/including-tripadvisor-widget-in-angularjs-app) - here is the code that I tried from that answer:

```
<div id="TA_cdsscrollingravenarrow993" class="TA_cdsscrollingravenarrow"><ul id="QAlUXL" class="TA_links ZECPTIZB"><li id="esd1SQAAb" class="VkzA66nOe"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/">
```

But this sadly doesn't fix my problem, I get the same results, you can see the widget in the upper right corner of this page:

http://bellamontereybay.com/

Comment: Are you including the external script tag in the component or inside your index.html file? Angular will remove it from components.

Comment: I'm putting it right in my angular template, not in the js component

Comment: put 
`<script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsscrollingravenarrow?amp;locationId=1529483&amp;border=true&amp;uniq=993&amp;lang=en_US&amp;display_version=2"></script>`
 in the index.html file. Keep the rest of the code in the template.

Comment: I will give that a shot and report back, thanks!

Comment: I tried that and same result, I see the Tripadvisor logo but none of the scripted content.

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the error console?

Comment: @Nick - no errors at all in the console.

Comment: @haakon.io have you found a solution?